# Differences between C++ OOP and PHP OOP

Tags: php, c++, oop

I started learning OOP applied to C++. Now I want to know if I am required to read a entire section of a book about PHP's OOP or just to adapt some little things?

Are there major differences between these two languages or subtle ones that will occur in a proeminent maner?

Thanks

Comment: Same concepts apply - inheritance, interfaces, `public, private, protected`, instance vs static properties. Syntax differs. C++ supports multiple inheritance, PHP does not -- that may be the biggest difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally the only difference is that while it is a good idea to make abstract classes and interfaces in C++/Java, you don't really need to do so nearly as much in a dynamic language such as php, because you are not limited by types.  Although it may still be a good idea even if to simply document the code, a lot of times it just adds to the mess.

And as of recent php update, you can use mix-ins (traits).

Answer (score 1):

OOP is OOP and the language cant change the basic concepts of OOP. In PHP, i think only the difference of inheritance differs as it dont support multiple inheritance like java left all concepts stands same and only syntax changes.